# Excel: Ctrl + DownArrow action

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

Anybody please tell me which action program does when I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> hotkey?

I know that program navigates down to the next non-empty cell. But when I create Excel document from Excel.Interop the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>↓</kbd> doesn't work like it have to. It navigates to the last cell in the column...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm sorry for being not so clear. I don't care about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> behaviour actually. I'm concerning about what causes data acting like one big cell?

Comment: I'm sure there is no difference in navigation key behavior whether the doc was created using Excel.Interop or created interactively with Excel.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the key stroke or macro behaviour? if macro behaviour `Range.end(xldown)` (whatever the C# equivalent of that is

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey,

Not sure what you mean by, "acting like one big cell".  If you want to get the entire used area of a sheet, used the property `UsedRange` on the `Worksheet` object.  It will return a two-dimensional array of the used range for that `Worksheet`.  I've used it when a `Worksheet` contained all the data in a table.  Much easier than iterating the Worksheet.

Cheers!